# Database Design For Course Registration & Pricing

Tags: sql, database, database-design

How would you design the table(s) to handle a registration form and pricing for an upcoming event?

As seen in the table below:

```
+-----------------------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------+
|      Occupation/Level       |   Optional Item   | Base Price | Early Bird Price |
+-----------------------------+-------------------+------------+------------------+
| Residents                   |                   | $1000      | $800             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| Practitioners               | Exam Prep (+$500) | $1500      | $1300            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| OBYGN Consultant - Friday   |                   | $800       | $900             |
| OBYGN Consultant - Saturday |                   | $800       | $900             |
| OBYGN Consultant - Sunday   |                   | $600       | $700             |
| OBYGN Consultant - All Days |                   | $1900      | $2100            |
+-----------------------------+-------------------+------------+------------------+
```

- different prices are charged based on the attendee's occupation.
- practitioners have access to an optional exam preparation session for an additional fee
- OBGYN Consultants have the option of registering for single/multiple days; each of which charges a different amount

To further illustrate the details, here's a screenshot of the old registration form.
[image]

My initial idea is to keep it very simple and treat each line separately and store the amount with it. The days which an OBGYN Consultant may choose simply become another line in the table.

```
+----+---------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| ID |     Occupation/Level      | Base Price     | Early Bird Price |
+----+---------------------------+----------------+------------------+
|  1 | Residents                 | $1000          | $800             |
|  2 | Practitioners             | $1500          | $1300            |
|  4 | OBYGN_Consultant_Friday   | $800           | $900             |
|  5 | OBYGN_Consultant_Saturday | $800           | $900             |
|  6 | OBYGN_Consultant_Sunday   | $600           | $700             |
|  7 | OBYGN_Consultant_All_Days | $1900          | $2100            |
+----+---------------------------+----------------+------------------+
```

The *optional_materials* table would handle any courses that have additional options.

```
+----+----------+-----------+--------+
| ID | CourseID |   Name    | Amount |
+----+----------+-----------+--------+
|  1 |        2 | Exam Prep | $500   |
+----+----------+-----------+--------+
```

See any major issues with this design OR see a better way of handling it?

Comment: Your new model does not account for the subdivision of the "OBYGN" schedules. I don't know if that's important. Do you plan to hard code that relationship in the app? Apart from that I don't see any major issue.

Comment: Good point. Are you referring to a lookup table like _occupation_types_? That would allow my application code to loop over the types and output a radio button for each one in the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how flexible you want to be in the future. If you for example want to have a super early bird price next year or you will support different currencies then I would make it like this:

```
+----+----------+---------------------------+------------+-------+----------+
| ID | CourseID |           Title           | Price Type | Price | Currency |
+----+----------+---------------------------+------------+-------+----------+
|  1 |        1 | Residents                 | Base       |  1000 | Dollar   |
|  2 |        1 | Residents                 | Early      |   800 | Dollar   |
|  3 |        2 | Practitioners             | Base       |  1500 | Dollar   |
|  4 |        2 | Practitioners             | Early      |  1300 | Dollar   |
|  5 |        4 | OBYGN_Consultant_Friday   | Base       |   800 | Dollar   |
|  6 |        4 | OBYGN_Consultant_Friday   | Early      |   900 | Dollar   |
|  7 |        5 | OBYGN_Consultant_Saturday | Base       |   800 | Dollar   |
|  8 |        5 | OBYGN_Consultant_Saturday | Early      |   900 | Dollar   |
|  9 |        6 | OBYGN_Consultant_Sunday   | Base       |   600 | Dollar   |
| 10 |        6 | OBYGN_Consultant_Sunday   | Early      |   700 | Dollar   |
| 11 |        7 | OBYGN_Consultant_All_Days | Base       |  1900 | Dollar   |
| 12 |        7 | OBYGN_Consultant_All_Days | Early      |  2100 | Dollar   |
+----+----------+---------------------------+------------+-------+----------+
```

But overall your approach is totally valid.

Also concider adding a "Created" and "Edited" date field in the end. Makes it easier to keep transparency over data changes (maybe you want to highlight options that are only available or have changed over last 14 days or so)

Comment: Great idea re: price type. That could point to a _price_type_info_ table which has the valid date ranges.